# How to remove search history in Popcorn Time in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

How can I remove the search history in Popcorn Time in Ubuntu? I tried to uninstall it then reinstalling it again, deleted cashes... but none of them worked for me.

Comment: That what it returns:  `.  ..  share`

Comment: `rm -rf /home/$USER/.cache/Popcorn-Time`

Comment: if it doesn't work try : `rm -rf /home/$USER/.config/Popcorn-Time`

Comment: The second one worked for me :-) Thanks! Can you put it as an answer not comment? @kenn

Comment: @kenn you should post that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popcorn-Time creates local files in `~/.cache/Popcorn-Time` for caching media files it downloads and in `~/.config/Popcorn-Time` for `Popcorn-Time` configuration options where it stores values.

So

```
 rm -rf /home/$USER/.cache/Popcorn-Time

 rm -rf /home/$USER/.config/Popcorn-Time
```

will reset `Popcorn-Time` to its defaults and remove search history.